# Can I install a valve-type toilet with an old elevated type tank?

Tags: toilet

Unfortunately my house does not have an attic, so I cannot put a large reservoir there, which would the ideal for running a valve-type (tankless) toilet.

Can I install instead one of those old fashion pull chain type type tanks (like in the "Godfather") high near the ceiling and then feed it to the valve on the toilet? Will that work, or does it require a higher drop?

Comment: Can you give us more info on the stool or bottom half of the toilet most toilets sold in the U.S. are low flush from memory those elevated tank units were 5 or more gallon flush.

Comment: @EdBeal Assume that the basin is a standard commercial bowl which is designed for use with a commercial flush valve.

Comment: I think you could do it I would want to seal that opening at the toilet with a rubber seal. And use a large PVC pipe from the tank to the stool 1-1/2"? Possibly 2". A plumbing speciality store might even have the parts you need.

Comment: You are talking about a pilot assist valve I hope these Basicly flush until the pressure is equalized in the valve using a diphram. You would have flow but maybe not enough pressure as I remember there is a jet that shoots down the drain to pull water out while adding water at the rim.

Answer (score 0):

Fifty years ago for two years I used one of those old fashioned elevated tanks about 7 ft or more above the toilet, and it flushed great, but was noisy. You gave a vigorous pull on a chain and it started a siphon.

However, this went directly into the toilet; it did not go through a valve as on a commercial toilet. I would bet those require 25 psi minimum and maybe 35 psi which would require 58 ft of head or 80 ft, respectively.

[commercial toilet](https://www.ehow.com/how_12084443_increase-flushing-pressure-commercial-toilet.html)

> Water supply specifications for a typical manual commercial toilet
>   flush valve such as the Kohler K-13517 call for a static pressure of
>   35 pounds per square inch and a flow of 25 gallons per minute.

Comment: Had one in the basement of my old house. Tank was only about 5 feet above the bowl, with 1.5" pipe. The pull chain was awesome. Likely there are several different design possibilities.